# Select from MySQL AWS into Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a MySQL DB on AWS.
I want to run a few simple SQL statements that select data from MySQL and insert to Azure DB.
Something like
select *
into Azure_Table
from
MySQL_Table
I also want to schedule this on a daily basis.
How can I do it directly from Azure SQL without having to use Data Factory / SSIS
Thank you

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data Ingestion in ADF.

[image]

You can select the source and sink. Then schedule as per your need.

[image]

**Note:** Since you have the Source as **MySQL on AWS** i.e. outside of Azure Cloud, you would have to setup **Self-hosted integration runtime** for the linked service at source. Follow official MS doc for [Setting up a self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#setting-up-a-self-hosted-integration-runtime) using UI.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can follow this blog [Copying data from AWS RDS MySQL into Azure through Data Factory Integration Runtime](https://fabriciosanchez-en.azurewebsites.net/copying-data-from-aws-rds-mysql-into-azure-through-data-factory-integration-runtime/) 
Published by Fabricio Sanchez

Answer (score 0):

You can Migrate Amazon RDS for MySQL to Azure Database for MySQL using MySQL Workbench.

You can refer to below official documentation where you can get step by step explanation:

- [Migrate Amazon for MySQL to Azure Database for MySQL using MySQL Workbench.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/how-to-migrate-rds-mysql-workbench)

**Workaround** – There is no direct way to query third-party database from Azure. But, you can migrate it to Azure and then perform operations.